# Robolectric ShadowPath

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to use ShadowPath to test that a renderer produces the points that I expect, but I must be missing something with trying to get it to run.

```
public void test() {
  ShadowPath shadowPath = Robolectric.shadowOf(new Path());
  drawToPath(shadowPath);
  List<Point> points = path.getPoints();
  ...assertPoints...
}

public void drawToPath(Path path) {
  path.moveTo(x, y);
  path.drawTo(x1, y1);
  ...
}
```

Clearly I cannot pass shadowPath to drawToPath() since it does not subclass Path but how else would it intercept the moveTo and drawTo methods.

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Comment: Also, calling "new Path()" to give it to shadowOf(instance) throws the Stub exception, so I'm really missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is magic, and don't pass the shadow around.

Robolectric.shadoOf(instance) injects callbacks into the original path instance and you pass the path instance around to be used.  You can call getPoints on the ShadowPath instance to get the points added to the original instance.

As for the Stub exception when instantiating the Path instance, I had a setup problem
@RunWith was still set to JUnit4.class instead of RobolectricTestRunner.class meaning that I couldn't actually instantiate the Path.